# Linking a DLL in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005

I'm using Visual Studio C++ 2005 on Windows XP.

I have created a DLL shared library using Visual Studio C++ 2005.

However, I am not sure how to link it. Normally I have just created the static libraries (*.lib).

Do I link the same way I would when linking a library. By using the properties C/C++ and linker general properties and selecting the path for the headers and library paths?

Many thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create the DLL there should be a .lib file created for the purpose of dynamic linking. You can use these just as you would static .lib files.

Comment: And is there a location of where the compiler will know where to find the DLL itself? Do I still need to enter the DLL name in the input for the linker properties? Thanks.

Comment: @ant2009 Often you just place it in the same folder as the executable, but that's just one choice. But since we don't know the full story of how you intend to use and share this DLL it's hard to give concrete advice.

Comment: I think keeping it in the same location as the executable is ok for this application. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This [article](http://www.lurklurk.org/linkers/linkers.html#windowsdlls) explains Windows dlls well.

> The .LIB file associated with a DLL
>   describes what (exported) symbols are
>   present in the DLL, together with
>   their locations.

Answer (score 1):

To put it simply:

- When you link: you Need Lib, not DLL
- When you run it: you need dll, not lib (Put the DLL with your executable)